# Is there a command similar to nocite(*) for gls (glossaries) and is there a glossary package similar to To­bias Oetiker's?

Tags: xetex, memoir, glossaries

I use the class `memoir` and compile in XeLaTeX.

I would like to print glossaries in a separated file and to ignore all `gls`. I do not write any `gls` in anywhere. Similar to `\nocite{*}`. Also similar to To­bias Oetiker's [acronym.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym).

Imagine like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}

  \nogls(*)
  \include{gloassries.tex}
\end{document}
```

The separated file `glossaries.tex`:

```
\newglossaryentry{Cloud}
{
    name=Cloud,
    description={shared pools of configurable computer system resources and higher-level services that can be rapidly provisioned with minimal management effort, often over the Internet.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Docker}
{
    name=Docker,
    description={a computer program that performs operating-system-level virtualization, also known as "containerization".}
}
```

Derived from Tobias' acronym.sty, imagine like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}
  \include{gloassries.tex}
\end{document}
```

The separated file `glossaries.tex`

```
\chapter*{Glossaries}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossaries}
\markboth{GLOSSARIES}{GLOSSARIES}

\begin{glossary}
{\small
\glo{Cloud}{shared pools of configurable computer system resources and higher-level services that can be rapidly provisioned with minimal management effort, often over the Internet.}
\glo{Docker}{a computer program that performs operating-system-level virtualization, also known as "containerization".}
}
\end{glossary}
```

Is it possible?

#### Update

Because I searched for the questions, tried all the codes and they did not work. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands, dvipsnames]{memoir}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \include{acronimos}

    \clearpage

    \glsaddall
    \input{capitulos/glossario.tex}
    \printglossaries

    \backmatter
    \nocite{*}
    \begin{raggedright}
    \printbibliography
    \end{raggedright}

\end{document}
```

### Update 2

I also have moved to the preamble but it did not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands, dvipsnames]{memoir}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\input{capitulos/glossario.tex}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \include{acronimos}

    \clearpage

    \glsaddall
    \printglossaries

    \backmatter
    \nocite{*}
    \begin{raggedright}
    \printbibliography
    \end{raggedright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\glsaddall`, see the documentation. And better don't use \include but \input.

Comment: Then it does not work either.

Comment: Do you load the glossaries definitions before the command?

Comment: Yes, it does. I will upload the post

Comment: Ready, please check the end.

Comment: You do not load the definitions early enough. Move `\input{capitulos/glossario.tex}` to your preamble.

Comment: I also did it and it does not work either.

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you call the makeglossaries command?

Comment: Yes, I did, check again the update 2

Comment: That doesn't show if you called makeglossaries (this is not the `\makeglossaries` in the document but an application like biber).

Comment: I always run xelatex > biber > xelatex^2.

Comment: And now you will have to run `xelatex > biber > makeglossaries > xelatex` (if you want some sorting, for simpler output variants see Nicola's answer and the documentation).

Comment: I like glossaries-extra because it does not require the command `makeglossaries`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest method if you want to list all defined terms in the order of definition:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{Cloud}
{
    name=Cloud,
    description={shared pools of configurable computer system resources and higher-level services that can be rapidly provisioned with minimal management effort, often over the Internet.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Docker}
{
    name=Docker,
    description={a computer program that performs
    operating-system-level virtualization, also known as 
   ``containerization''.}
}

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

If you want an abbreviation list as well:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[sort=none,abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{Cloud}
{
    name=Cloud,
    description={shared pools of configurable computer system resources and higher-level services that can be rapidly provisioned with minimal management effort, often over the Internet.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Docker}
{
    name=Docker,
    description={a computer program that performs
    operating-system-level virtualization, also known as
   ``containerization''.}
}

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

If you want to change the style or the order that the lists are displayed, you need to use `\printunsrtglossary` for each list:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[sort=none,abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{Cloud}
{
    name=Cloud,
    description={shared pools of configurable computer system resources and higher-level services that can be rapidly provisioned with minimal management effort, often over the Internet.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Docker}
{
    name=Docker,
    description={a computer program that performs
    operating-system-level virtualization, also known as
   ``containerization''.}
}

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossary % default: style=list, type=main
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,style=long]
\end{document}
```

There are [lots of predefined styles](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles).

If your definitions are in an external file, [use `\input` not `\include`](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#include) in the preamble.

The above examples don't perform any sorting. If you want the lists sorted automatically then you need to use one of the [indexing methods described in the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:indexingoptions) and [incorporate the appropriate external tool into your document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries), as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Lists sorted automatically... do you mean sort alphabetically?

Comment: @GustavoReis I meant automatically sorting the lists in alphabetical order :-) (Rather than just listing the terms in the order in which you defined them.)

Comment: Sorry, @nicola-talbot, I received an error when I wrote `name=Google Cloud Container Registry`. I see that the glossaries-extra accepts only one word and not more than two words.

Comment: @GustavoReis That should work as long as the value doesn't contain a comma or braces, but try grouping the value: `name={Google Cloud Container Registry}`. What's the error message?